# Does Visual Studio 2010 have a 64bit version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am really confused, I am trying to read about its new features but some pages in google come up with 64bit versions, but not in MS' official site.

To my knowledge MS decided to keep it 32bit for the time being for VS 2010. Is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rico Mariani, dev boss for VS2010 [has blogged](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) about the reasoning behind not creating a 64-bit version (yet).  Not an official opinion of course, just a some insight from somebody that was very closely involved.  He left the team btw.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why he left the team btw?

Comment: It sounded like burn-out to me.  However, Mr. Mariani has made drastic moves before.  VS2010 was a difficult project, they were battling perf problems badly.  His specialty.

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no 64 bit version of Visual Studio yet. The confusion probably comes from the fact that Visual Studio allows you to generate 64 bit binaries but the application itself is 32 bit.

Answer (score 4):

There is no 64 bit version BUT you can install it on 64 bit.

[Here's why...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Visual Studio is a 32 bit application. Here's some more info, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx