# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for x64?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, msdn

I have an x64 machine and an MSDN subscription. I want to download VS2010 Ultimate. However, I'm not seeing an x64 version on the subscriber downloads page. Why might this be? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why would you want a x64 version of VS? The 32-bit version runs fine on x64 machines, and contains x64 compilers.

Comment: See [Hardware Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/system-requirements)

Comment: @CyberShadow if there's no difference, then I don't care. I just wanted to make sure I got the right version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Visual Studio 2010 have a 64bit version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743475/does-visual-studio-2010-have-a-64bit-version)

Comment: @CyberShadow: after a year since this post been created, I need this too because I'd like to be able to host x64 bit services using VS2010. Otherwise I am running out of memory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because there isn't one. Here is a discussion: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no 64-bit version of VS2010.  Can't find a good prooflink, only this one:
http://www.ditii.com/2009/06/12/visual-studio-2010-will-be-32-bit-exclusive-no-64-bit/

EDIT: but it does include everything you need to create 64bit apps -- just like 2005 did.  Except on 2010, I believe, the cross-compile stuff is installed by default.